# How to write spring data query using Aggregation.project method

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to write an equivalent Spring data code using Aggregation.project method to get the result for the below stage (project stage in aggregations - Mongo DB)

```
$project:
        {
          _id:0,
          'id':1,
          'displayid':1,
          'level':{'$add':[{'$size':'$childlevels'}, 1]}
        }
```

Output :

```
        displayId: "ABCD"
        id: 125
        level: 4
```

'level' field shows the result of the sum of (array size of childlevels from previous stage +1).

I am thinking of something like below, but this is not giving the expected result.

```
    ProjectionOperation projectStage = Aggregation.project()
            .andExclude("_id")
            .andInclude(ID)
            .andInclude(DISPLAY_ID)
            .andExpression("{'$add':[{'$size':'$childlevels'}, 1]}").as("level");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned what error/result you are getting. But this should work.

```
ProjectionOperation projectStage = Aggregation.project()
    .andExclude("_id")
    .andInclude("id")
    .andInclude("displayId")
    .and(ArithmeticOperators.Add.valueOf(ArrayOperators.Size.lengthOfArray("childlevels")).add(1)).as("level");
```